# Iterate through sub collection and documents- angularfirestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

Am trying to access a subcollection from a firestore, I have all the values in the data variable, when I try to print the values am getting an error InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

The "data" from the below code snippet has the following values

```
      data:{
      "Kids Pool":           
     {"Chlorine":"Present","Color":"Nil","Turbidity":"Nil","pH":"Neutral"},
     "Main Pool": 
      {"Chlorine":"Nil","Color":"Green","Turbidity":"Yes","pH":"7"},
      "id":"Swimming Pool"}

   this.dieselGeneratorCollections = 
   this.afs.collection('apartments/1001- 
   SJR Verity/Daily Readings');  
   this.posts = this.dieselGeneratorCollections.valueChanges();
   this.dailyReadings = 
   this.dieselGeneratorCollections.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
         data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
         console.log("data:"+JSON.stringify(data) );
        return data; 
      });
    }));
```

In my html code am trying to print the values for ID "Swimming Pool",

```
 <ul *ngFor="let dailyReading of dailyReadings | async">     
  <strong>{{ dailyReading.id }}</strong>
 <ul *ngIf = "dailyReading.id == 'Diesel Generator'"  >
       <ul>  <strong>Diesel Leval: {{ dailyReading.dieselLevel }}</strong> 
 </ul>
        <ul>  <strong>Energy Reading: {{ dailyReading.energyReading }} 
 </strong></ul>
       <ul>   <strong>Running Hours: {{ dailyReading.runningHours }} 
 </strong></ul>
 </ul>

<ul>   <strong>Running Hours: {{ dailyReading.KidsPool }}</strong></ul>
<div *ngFor="let swimmingPool of dailyReading.KidsPool | async" >
    <strong>Chlorine: {{ swimmingPool.Chlorine }}</strong>
</div>      
</ul>
```

how do I print the values of "swimmingPool"

Comment: Why have another `async` here -> `<div *ngFor="let swimmingPool of dailyReading.KidsPool | async" >` ?? . Then `kidsPool` is an Object, no need to loop over the object (and can't loop this way either). Just access the props of kidsPool

Comment: Unless the `dailyReading.KidsPool` is an observable, you don't need to use the `async` pipe. `dailyReading.KidsPool` doesn't look an array either, yet you are trying to iterate it like it was. You could try [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).